# Page navigation not showing even tho it should

Tags: php, pagination

EDIT: I replaced the pagenavi which is not native to wordpress with the_posts_pagination. Now i get no pagination at all, it just shows the 4 posts how it's supposed, but no pagination (yes i have more then 4 posts in the category). Can anyone help me figure it out? :P

Can anyone tell me why the pagination doesn't do anything else except for just sitting there and looking pretty ? Before i added the pagenavi plugin, i tried making the pagination show with the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) ) but there would be no output and no pagination. Now the pagination is showing but it does absolutely nothing ...

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( $category->name != "Uncategorized" ) {
        //****Set attributes
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'category_name' => $category->name,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        //****Get the posts
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );         
        //****Display the posts
        ?>
        <section class="category_<?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php
        //Category name and number of posts
        echo "<p> The name of the category is <span class='category_title'>".$category->name."</span> and the number of posts is ".$category->count."</p>";
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php } 
        echo '</ul>';
        the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) );

        </section><?php
        //****Reset posts
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }       
}
```

Comment: what type of page are you trying to do this on? `paged` is the archive pagination query var, `page` is the singular pagination query var. some pagination functions will only work on non-singular pages.

Comment: I really don't know what type of page it is, but i'm guessing it's singular? I mean the page it's supposed to be a template page, and right now it only has a get_header(), get_footer() and a div container for the code above,

Comment: I think you should ask to WP-PageNav support team because the non-working paginate links are built by that plugin, and so the `page`, `paged` or any other pagination query var is also generated by the plugin.

Comment: I didn't use WP-PageNav because i wanted to, but it was the only option that showed the pagination. I tried using "the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size' => 2 ) )" instead of page_navi but it didn't even show the pagination. I don't really care if it's pagenavi or native wp pagination, all i need is for it to work :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a fix:

just need to replace this:

```
the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) );
```

with:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'mid_size' => 2
));
```

Comment: I have the same issue: `the_posts_pagination($args)` doesn't show a thing at all. However, using `paginate_links` does show sort of random links and does not work properly. Also, using a different function shouldn't be the final answer to a question, why `the_posts_pagination` doesn't work.